# Why use HttpParams object for using query parameters in the request in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I noticed that there are two ways of adding query parameters to HTTP requests in angular. I was not sure which approach to follow in my application.

1.Append the query parameters as strings to the URL as below :

```
let value1='...', value2='...';
const url = `${this.baseUrl}?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`;
this.http.get(url).subscribe(...);
```

2.Use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) object to add the query parameters and use it while making the API call as below :

```
let baseUrl='...', value1='...', value2='...';
let params = new HttpParams()
               .set('param1', value1);
               .set('param2', value2);
this.http.get(baseUrl, {params: params}).subscribe(...);
```

I was wondering which is the better approach among the two and why? Or which scenarios are best suited for each of these methods?

Comment: If `${this.baseUrl}` is changed to itself include url params or hash string, code #1 breaks.

Answer (score 0):

HttpParams comes with a set of handy functions if you have some complex logic before sending params (append for example).

It also does the "?" and "&" logic by itself which means you don't need to worry about param1 if it was not set, example :

```
const params = new HttpParams();
if (param1) {
  params.set('param1', param1);
}
if (param2) {
   // Here with a string concatenation you would need to do "if first param then ? else &"
   params.set('param2', param2);
}
```

Yet those two syntaxes are valid and the choice might be opiniated ?

Comment: What if there are special characters or spaces in the `value1` or `value2` field? Then would both the approached give the same result?

Comment: I know that HttpParams automatically encodes your values, I'm not sure how http behaves with a string (if it encodes it or not), you should try it and see the difference